# Date subtracting 1 from my DAY Value in my date dropdown bar VUE.js mySQL

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For some reason, I am having problems getting my date select text box to display the proper DAY in my mm/dd/yyyy section. It seems to be subtracting one off of the day when I select january 4th it will display January 3rd. If any advice could be spared it would be greatly appreciated, as I am a mere novice.

Here is some code supporting this problem, if any more information or code is needed feel free to ask.

This is my AddEntry.vue page

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      location: "",
      endUser: "",
      orderNumber: "",
      date: null,
      application: "",
      serviceTech: "",
      department: "",
      hours: 0,
      travelHours: 0,
      contactName: "",
      reason: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    serviceEntry() {
      let tmpEntry = {};
      tmpEntry.location = this.location;
      tmpEntry.endUser = this.endUser;
      tmpEntry.orderNumber = this.orderNumber;
      tmpEntry.date = this.date;
      tmpEntry.application = this.application;
      tmpEntry.serviceTech = this.serviceTech;
      tmpEntry.department = this.department;
      tmpEntry.hours = this.hours;
      tmpEntry.travelHours = this.travelHours;
      tmpEntry.contactName = this.contactName;
      tmpEntry.reason = this.reason;
      return tmpEntry;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    setServiceDate(event) {
      // alert(event.target.valueAsDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US'))
      this.date = event.target.valueAsDate;
      // alert(this.date)
    },
    formatDate(date) {
      var d = new Date(date),
        month = "" + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = "" + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

      if (month.length < 2) month = "0" + month;
      if (day.length < 2) day = "0" + day;

      return [year, month, day].join("-");
    },
    async submitItem() {
      if (this.$store.dispatch("createServiceEntry", this.serviceEntry))
        this.$router.push({
          path: `/`,
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.date = new Date();
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to just install `moment` package?

Comment: Like I said above, I am a novice, hence, I do not even know what that is. How do I use it? I was also curious if there is  a problem with my code? I've read that it could be something wrong with mySQL, but the only inclination is that it could be set in a different time zone

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. It's because the date is stored with a time and sometimes the timezone is different between the application and the browser viewing it.

One work-around is to strip the timezone if you only care about dd/mm/yyyy

```
computed: {
  fixedDate() {
    const date = new Date(this.date).toString().substring(0,15)
    return date
  },
  // you would use {{ fixedDate }} in your html template
  ...
}
```

What this does is strip the timezone (UTC, for example, which is 6 hours ahead if you're in EST. Meaning anytime after 6pm, it could show as +1 days)

Comment: Thank you good sir. When I implement this, I get a Duplicate key 'computed' error, is there any where in the code above you would suggest placing this? Again sorry for my novice

Comment: The only way to get this error is if you already have something called "fixedDate" in computed or methods section of your component. Perhaps you added it to your computed section as "formatDate" but you left your old one in. Look for two keys in your component that are equal!